# Convert standalone Javascript to widget

Tags: javascript, widget, refactoring

We have an 8,300-line Javascript application, which implements an interactive diagram for a hand of bridge. It's currently written with about 250 top-level variables, 250 functions, about 130 lines of driver code outside of functions, and 30 hard-coded element IDs referenced in various places; it's entirely self-contained, no libraries are used. It gets its parameters from the URL query string. So the way we use it on web pages is to load it in an iframe.

This is implemented as 3 files:

- `handviewer.html` - This is the page we point to in iframes. It contains about 70 lines of HTML with all the required DIVs, and loads the CSS and JS (called `handviewer-old.html` in the test below)
- `hvstyles.css` - The CSS for the page
- `handviewer.js` - The Javascript code described above

In `handviewer.html`, the active elements have inline `onclick` attributes that call functions in `handviewer.js`.

The problem is that when we embed lots of these on a page, performance suffers.  Iframes are a pain to begin with, and lots of them all pointing to the same server run into connection limits. And even though they're all pointing at the same script, the parameters in the query string act as a cache-buster. Loading a page with 12 of these diagrams takes 3-5 seconds with reasonably fast browsers. Looking at the timeline, you can see that the loads are staggered. So I'd like to convert it to a widget that can be applied to a DIV, with the parameters as inline arguments.

A test page with these 12 iframes is at:

http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/many-hv-old.html

I'm preparing to do this by hand -- I'll wrap a function around the whole thing, replace the IDs with classes, so that `document.getElementById(x)` becomes `theDiv.getElementsByClass(x)[0]`, and rewrite the function that extracts query string parameters to get them from an options argument. But I wonder if there are any tools around that can assist in the process.  If anyone has done a conversion like this, do you have techniques that help?

Comment: you say that performance is the problem... Are you talking about preformance of downloading many files from server, or performance of processing lots of JS in browser?

Comment: From my testing in Developer Tools, it looks like there's some of both. I tried profiling it, but there didn't seem to be any one bottleneck in the code, CPU time was spread all over the place.

Comment: can you provide some link?

Comment: @IvanKuckir I've added a link to a test page showing this.

Comment: I see 3 files, which could not be found ... solve it, so we can move on

Comment: @IvanKuckir Sorry, handviewer.html has a different name on the test site, I've updated above. But the other 2 files are as I described.

Comment: I still see lots of not found files ... I think your page is slow, because browser still waits for them to load

Comment: OK, some image files I forgot about copying to dev server. THey're there now. Doesn't seem to improve page load time.

Comment: OK, so the problem is, that your page is running some CPU-heavy Javascript. It takes 11 seconds to run it in all the iframes. Problematic function is "resizeCards". It consumes 90% of the CPU time. Try to optimize that.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that function pop to the top of the profile. It was hard to tell when I profiled it, Chrome's profiler said 90+% was used by "idle", so resizeCards only used about 2.5%. How do you filter out idle time in the profiler?

Comment: Just stop the profiler in the right time, or "subtract" idle time. BTW. I updated my answer.

Comment: I read this question and I want to help you or maybe learn from you. but your link is not working.

Comment: @imsiso The IFRAMEs make AJAX calls to a database, but the records it was querying have been deleted since then. The code is still there, though.

Comment: ok I checked this http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/handviewer.html but all I see is some boxes that not works but I found the `jsbig.js` which is really big but why you have put it in end?

Comment: and also where the performance you are talking about comes in?

Comment: I was wrong, it's not a database issue, I had just deleted handviewer-old.html. I think handviewer.html is the same, I renamed it. The performance issue is mostly noticeable when you embed multiple viewers on one page -- doing them one at a time is acceptable.

Comment: yes I see - its too much when we load them together.(-: but some of the time is for runing js code and some for loading data and images to browser. and about js I should check it first.

Comment: sorry for my late reply I was busy with a work too, now I'm completely free. I took a look at your js creating a widget as you mentioned would be a big help in performance and other things but what you mean than tools around that can assist in the process? there is code help you manage your codes like code give you a base ie. `rich class base` or jquery plugin ability that help you make a widget or coffee script that helps you write and generate your code more smarty but if you mean an automatic thing that make that I don't know about it if exists?

Comment: But I can became your tool (I mean I can and also like to help you in that if you want) would you mind explain?

Comment: I'm not really working on this project at the moment.

Comment: OK, btw I read your profile and as I now think you are enough experienced to know how to do things so much better than me and I will learn from you instead of helping you but the thing I might be able to help you in is the new technologies and codes that would help you and give you ability to do things better and to deal with weaknesses of javascript like 'coffee script' , 'class.js' and 'controller.js' in jmvc.com 'backbone.js' etc. . But anyhow I would be happy if I could 'help you' and/or 'learn from you' so please let me know if you wanted. (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code ...

if(cardDivs[seat][suit][i].innerHTML=="") ...

Don't do that. Make a classic JS array of booleans to mark "empty items".

And generally, don't access DOM too much. It seems, that your whole "model" (from MVC terminology) and application state is stored in DOM.

Comment: Actually, it's in two files. I'll update the question with this detail.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see how much I gain.

Comment: I've removed some of the DOM accesses out of inner loops, and cached some of the information in JS variables.  A handful of these changes has improved loading time by about 40%, so it looks like this is the right approach.  resizeCards is still the bottleneck, I think the problem is that it sets inline CSS for 208 DIVs -- each hand has a DIV for every potential card it could hold times 4 hands. Normally they're all the same fontSize, and we could inherit from a containing DIV, but if a player holds a really long suit, it has to shrink the cards in that suit to fit them in the box.